# How to use loops in conditional statements in Python?

Tags: python, loops, logic

I want to check if a list contains only a specific element (in my case its None)

I believe there is a pythonic way of doing it, I tried:
`if mydict[direction] == None for direction in DIRECTIONS: ...`

but this obviously doesn't work

In other words I need a PYTHONIC way that allows me to shorten the next code:

```
def ispure(element)
    for direction in DIRECTIONS:
        if mydict[direction] != element
            return False
        else:
            pass
    return True
```

Hopefully I am being clear and thanks in advance.

Comment: your question is not clear, can you explain with some examples ?

Comment: I think you can try `filter`

Comment: If you are testing for `None` only, how about just `if None in mydict: ...`?

Comment: Something like `all(i is None for i in your_list)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple solutions, so you can pick your poison. Assuming `a` is a list of 100 `None`s, here are some that I could think of (sorted by performance on my machine):

---

Using `set`:

```
def only_element(element, ls):
    return set(ls) == set([element])
```

Timing:

```
$ python -m timeit 'set(a) == set([None])'
100000 loops, best of 5: 3.06 µs per loop
```

---

Using `all`:

```
def only_element(element, ls):
    return all([item == element for item in ls])
```

Timing:

```
$ python -m timeit 'all([item == None for item in a])'
50000 loops, best of 5: 8.81 usec per loop
```

---

Using a `for` loop:

```
def only_element(element, ls):
    for item in ls:
        if item != element:
            return False
    return True
```

Timing:

```
$ python -m timeit 'for item in a:\n    if item != None:\n        break'
100000 loops, best of 5: 9.16 µs per loop
```

---

Using `filter`:

```
def only_element(element, ls):
    return len(list(filter(lambda x: x != element, ls))) == 0
```

Timing:

```
$ python -m timeit 'len(list(filter(lambda x: x != None, a))) == 0'
10000 loops, best of 5: 20.8 usec per loop
```

---

**What's the takeaway?**

Usually, there's a built-in function that suits your needs better and runs faster (and with less code) than if you were to use a `for` loop.

Comment: The first solution is very smart, simple and intuitive I will stick to that, but can you explain the _all() function_ I looked at the documentation but I don't quite get it.

Comment: Sure! The `all` function takes in a list of elements and returns if all of them are truthy. Things that are falsy (the opposite) include `0`, `[]` (the empty list), and of course `False`. If any of those are in the list that is the input to `all`, the return value would be `False`. In this example, the list is converted to a list of booleans, each representing whether that item was the desired element. The `all` call will check if there are any `False`s (meaning, if there were any elements that weren't desired) and will return `False` if so.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest (and not as efficient) way is:
`len(list(filter(lambda direction: mydict[direction] is not None, DIRECTIONS))) == 0`

If you want to be more efficient and not go through all the elements in case the condition was false somewhere in the middle of the list, you can use `takewhile`:

`from itertools import takewhile
   len(list(takewhile(lambda direction: mydict[direction] is not None, DIRECTIONS))) == len(DIRECTIONS)`

Comment: Whoa!! complex solution, you must be smart :)